# Create a claim environment for nested claims inside theorem proofs using thmtools

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, theorems, amsthm, thmtools

Consider the following declarations:

```
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, thmtools}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{remark}
```

I want to create a claim theorem which will be used for defining a claim inside the proof of a Theorem. For example,

```
\begin{proposition}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{claim}
            first claim
            \begin{proof}
                proof of first claim
            \end{proof}
        \end{claim}
        \begin{claim}
            second claim
            \begin{proof}
                proof of second claim
            \end{proof}
        \end{claim}
    \end{proof}
\end{proposition}
```

The first claim should be automatically labeled as "Claim 1", the second claim as "Claim 2", and so on. The text in the proof should be indented such that it's clear where the proof of the individual claim ends without the presence of a q.e.d. symbol.

How can we achieve this? I'm new to latex, so please bear with me.

**EDIT**: The result should like this:

```
\begin{theorem}
    Text
    \begin{proof}[Proof\textup:\nopunct]
        Some part of the proof of the main theorem ...\newline
        \;\;\;\;\textbf{Claim 1:} Text\newline
        \;\;\;\;\textit{Proof}: Line 1\newline
        \;\;\;\;Line 2\newline
        \;\;\;\;Last Line\newline
        \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\textbf{Claim 1.1:} Text\newline
        \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\textit{Proof}: Line 1\newline
        \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;Line 2\newline
        \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;Last Line\newline
        continuation of main theorem proof ...
    \end{proof}
\end{theorem}
```

The claim numbering should restart by 1 inside every new theorem proof. Moreover, the claim and its proof should be indented (like $\;\;\;\;$ would do inside an equation). If there is a further claim inside a claim, it should be numbered Claim 1.1 and again be indented (but this time with respect to the environmental claim). How can we do this?

Comment: Please provide a complete (but small) working example, rather than just code snippets.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have no working example, since I don't know how I need to declare the "claim" environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you are looking for output that looks something like this:

[image]

Assuming so, then the code below does this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, thmtools}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{remark}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}
\newlist{Claim}{description}{2}
\setlist[Claim]{labelindent=2em,leftmargin=*}
\newif\ifInsideClaim
\newcounter{claim}[theorem]
\newcounter{cclaim}[claim]
\renewcommand\theclaim{\arabic{claim}}
\renewcommand\thecclaim{\arabic{claim}.\arabic{cclaim}}
\let\originalqedsymbol\qedsymbol
\newenvironment{claim}{%
  % disable qed symbol if there is no star
  \let\qedsymbol\relax%
  \ifInsideClaim% we have a nested environment
    \refstepcounter{cclaim}%
    \let\theclaimcounter\thecclaim%
  \else%
    \refstepcounter{claim}%
    \let\theclaimcounter\theclaim%
    \InsideClaimtrue%
  \fi%
  \Claim\item[\textbf{Claim \theclaimcounter:}]%
}{\endClaim\InsideClaimfalse\let\qedsymbol\originalqedsymbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
   A  proposition.
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof}
  Start the proof.
    \begin{claim}
        first claim
        \begin{proof}
            proof of first claim
        \end{proof}
        \begin{claim}
            first subclaim
            \begin{proof}
                proof of first subclaim
            \end{proof}
        \end{claim}
    \end{claim}
    \begin{claim}
      Second claim
      \begin{proof}
        Proof of second claim
      \end{proof}
    \end{claim}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Here is a quick explanation of how this works:

- I have defined two counters `claim` and `cclaim` for the claim environment and the subclaim environment, respectively. The `claim` counter is numbered "inside" `theorem` and the `cclaim` counter inside the `claim` counter so that they are reset whenever their paraent counter changes.
- I have defined a `claim` environment and a boolean variable `\ifInClaim` to detect when the `claim` environement is nested. The code only allows claims and subclaims. It would be easy enough to allow further nesting but I doubt that you or your readers would want this.
- To achieve the requested indentation I have used the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package (and each claim environment is secretly a `description` environment in disguise). You can easily adjust the indentation of the claim environments by changing `2em` and `4em` in the `\setlist` lines of the code.
- **Edit** The qedsymbol is disabled during the claim environments by setting `\qedsymbol` equal to `\relax` and then restoring it to the original value at the end of the proof.

**EDIT**

Here is a slight variation of the code to allow three levels of subclaims. Rather than using the switch `\ifInClaim` and counters `claim` and `cclaim` the code below has counters `claimi`, `claimii`, and `claimiii` as well as a `claimlevel`. From memory this is similar to how nested `enumerate` environments are done (although, I am sure that these are done more efficiently...). It would be easy enough to extend the new framework to arbitrary levels of nesting, provided that you have wide enough paper.

Here is the new output:

[image]

...and here is the revised code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, thmtools, etoolbox}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = definition]{definition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{proposition}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem]{remark}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}
\newlist{Claim}{description}{3}% allow 3 levels of nesting
\setlist[Claim]{labelindent=2em,leftmargin=*}

\newcounter{claimlevel}% records nesting level
\newcounter{claimi}[theorem] % claim counters for each nesting level
\newcounter{claimii}[claimi]
\newcounter{claimiii}[claimii]
\renewcommand\theclaimi{\arabic{claimi}}
\renewcommand\theclaimii{\theclaimi.\arabic{claimii}}
\renewcommand\theclaimiii{\theclaimii.\arabic{claimiii}}
\let\originalqedsymbol\qedsymbol
\newenvironment{claim}{%
  % disable qed symbol if there is no star
  \let\qedsymbol\relax%
  \stepcounter{claimlevel}
  \refstepcounter{claim\roman{claimlevel}}%
  \Claim\item[\textbf{Claim \csuse{theclaim\roman{claimlevel}}:}]%
  }{\endClaim\addtocounter{claimlevel}{-1}\let\qedsymbol\originalqedsymbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
   A  proposition.
\end{proposition}
\begin{proof}
  Start the proof.
    \begin{claim}
        first claim
        \begin{proof}
            proof of first claim
        \end{proof}
        \begin{claim}
            first subclaim
            \begin{proof}
                proof of first subclaim
            \end{proof}
            \begin{claim}
                  first subsubclaim
                  \begin{proof}
                      proof of first subsubclaim
                  \end{proof}
            \end{claim}
        \end{claim}
    \end{claim}
    \begin{claim}
      Second claim
      \begin{proof}
        Proof of second claim
      \end{proof}
    \end{claim}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The original question says that "the proof of the individual claim ends without the presence of a q.e.d. symbol."  This makes sense -- the multiplicity of tombstones becomes confusing, especially the "extra" one following on the line after the end of the proof text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I also thought that this looked strange but I missed the requirement. I'll update.

Comment: Update looks good, but it would look better if the tombstone weren't on an entirely separate line (which might allow it to break to a new page).  Does `\qedhere` work here?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I agree. Unfortunately, `\qedhere` has no effect and I don't see an obvious way of moving it...

Comment: Since you've saved `\originalqedsymbol`, maybe you could try something like `\newcommand{\endlastclaim}{\let\qedsymbol\originalqedsymbol \qedhere}` and insert that just before the `\end{proof}` of the last claim.  (Not tested.)  It's possible that `\qedhere` might not even be needed in the definition.  (Fixing this has *got* to be possible.)

Comment: In your subclaim, shouldn't you still choose 2em for the ident? Otherwise the subclaim is indented twice. Moreover, if I compile this code, the "proof" line below a claim is not correctly aligned with the word "Claim": https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz6MF.png. Oh, and least the empty space between a claim (not a subclaim) and the word "proof" seems to be larger than the empty space between the proposition and the word "proof".

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, you're right, an indent of `2em` is better. I don't see the issue that with `Proof` being indented too much but I suspect that there may be a missing `%` at the end of one of the lines of the code that I posted so I'll update it and that should fix the problem.

Comment: @Andrew Even with your edit, the "C" of "Claim 1" is not aligned with the "P" of "Proof" in the line below. Take a look at my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz6MF.png.

Comment: @0xbadf00d On my computer, as shown in the screenshot posted above, the "Claim" and "Proof"align perfectly. To make completely sure I just copied my code above into a new file and compiled it and I again get the image posted above. So, something other than my code is causing your problem. It could be a copy-paste issue or, conceivably, a difference in TeX distribution (I'm using TeXLive 2019).

Comment: @Andrew I've compiled it on overleaf.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I had a look at overleaf and I see the same issue. Looking at the log files overleaf is still using TeXLive 2017 and, more importantly, version 3.5.2 of [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). If you download `enumitem.sty` from ctan (using the link that I just gave), and add it to your overleaf project this will fix the problem. (With the updated version of  `enumitem.sty` the MWE compiles without errors, but there is always a chance that the current version of `enumitem.sty` may be incompatible with other parts of the TeX installation on overleaf...)

Comment: How can I use the enumitem.sty on overleaf? I guess I need to remove my `\usepackage{enumitem}` everywhere, but what's the replacement? (Guess this is a dumb question, but I'm new to latex and don't know how to include a custom package.)

Comment: Okay, I renamed the file "myenumitem.sty", uploaded into the same folder as my main file (is it possible to place it in a subfolder?), changed `\ProvidesPackage{enumitem}` into `\ProvidesPackage{myenumitem}` (is this really necessary?) and then used `usepackage{myenumitem}` inside my document.

Comment: BTW: Take a look at the following example code: `\begin{proof}
        Let $\mu,\nu\in\mathcal M_1(E)$ with
        \begin{equation}
            (\mu-\nu)f=0\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in\mathcal C.
        \end{equation}
        \begin{claim}
            Let $B_i\in\mathcal B(E_i)$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$. Then $$\mu\left(\bigtimes_{i=1}^kB_i\right).$$
            \begin{proof}
            \end{proof}
        \end{claim}
    \end{proof}`. This is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgImo.png. Why is there such a huge spacing between the equation and the beginning of the claim?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I compiled this in overleaf and I don't see this; see https://www.overleaf.com/read/djbyfwzyhtdx. Not sure what the difference is. As you can see in my overleaf project, I uploaded version 3.8 of `enumitem.sty` (and I just called it `enumitem.sty`). Could there be something else in your preamble? The fact that I don't see this in overleaf (or on my computer) suggests that this is caused by something in your set up.

Comment: For some reason, I can reproduce it at the moment. However, two other things: (1) If I add a label after `\begin{claim}` and reference it with `\autoref` it doesn't render to "Claim 1", but simply "1". What's the reason for that? (2) If a claim environment starts immediately after the beginning of a theorem proof, there is (in my opinition) too much horizontal spacing between "Proof:" and "Claim 1:". How can I change that?

Comment: It's probably time you considered asking a new question as none of these issues are part of the OP. IMHO, my investigations on your behalf with overleaf are way beyond the call of duty especially since there's no hint of thanks on your part. This said, for `\autoref` you need to add `\newcommand\claimautorefname{Claim}
\newcommand\cclaimautorefname{Claim}` and for the spacing issues have a read of the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) manual.

Comment: Uh-huh. I actually followed the "guideline" to not write comments like "Thanks!", but upvote yor answer and comments instead. But, sure, thank you!

Comment: Actually, there is one situation where I need a third claim level. How do I need to modify the code? Clearly, I guess I need `\newif\ifInsideCClaim`, `\newcounter{ccclaim}[cclaim]`, `\renewcommand\theccclaim{\arabic{claim}.\arabic{cclaim}.\arabic{ccclaim}}` and `\newcommand\ccclaimautorefname{Claim}`, but I don't know how I need to alter the code inside `\newenvironment{claim}{ ... }`.

Comment: @0xbadf00d The easiest way to do this is with a slightly different design: rather than using `\ifInsideCClaim` it would be better to define claim counters `claimi`, `claimii`, `claimiii` etc and then you would need to use `\newlist{Claim}{description}{3}`.  I'll edit.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you, once again, for your edit. There is one remaining issue: If I end a theorem proof with a nested claim there is a huge vertical empty space. For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2X4L.png.

Comment: @Andrew Example code: `\begin{theorem}
    A theorem.
    \begin{proof}
        Proof of the theorem.
        \begin{claim}
            A claim.
            \begin{proof}
                Proof of the claim.
                \begin{claim}
                    A nested claim.
                    \begin{proof}
                        Proof of the nested claim.
                    \end{proof}
                \end{claim}
            \end{proof}
        \end{claim}
    \end{proof}
\end{theorem}`

Comment: This answer raises the warning "Negative labelwidth" though. Besides, generally I think using these environments (e.g. `proof`) in "unexpected context" will make it behave in unexpected ways (spurious spaces?)